# Delete search history from android settings app

Tags: 7.0-nougat, search, search-history

In Android, it's possible to search for a specific setting by tapping the magnifying glass icon at the top right corner of the Settings app and typing. However, I haven't found a way to remove earlier search queries.

There is a question how to clear this but it only works until android 6 marshmallow.

Is there a way to clear the search history, or, better, to remove a specific search in android 7 nougat?

I can't find search_index.db in the data folder of settings app. Where is this located now? I know it can be fixed by clearing data of settings app but I want to find the location of the search_index.db

Comment: Maybe in /data/user_de/0 as mentioned [here](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-5x/help/sms-mms-database-location-change-t3447133/amp/) for other db

Comment: Please self answer the question giving the complete path and details on clearing the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the files "search_index.db" and "search_index.db-journal" located in, data/user_de/0/com.android.settings/databases/